# How to show the html code inside the <pre><code> block in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to use [Highlightjs](http://highlightjs.org/) inside the jinja template of my Django blog posts.

I setup the body of the post as: {{ post.cuerpo|safe|linebreaks }} because I want to format with css the details but when using highligthjs the block of code is shown but not the inside html code.

This is the link -> http://www.jf-taberu.com.ve/archivo/12

Is there any solution to this? Django is getting this html code as part of the template.

Comment: Please don't link to the code. Instead, take the relevant code you are  trying to deal with and include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste some of your code relevant? I'm not sure what your problem is. If you want to display the code, maybe you need try 
`{% autoescape off %} {{your variable contains code}} {% end autoescape %}`.

Maybe you can paste some code, so we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: If there is code in your variable `post.cuerpo`, you should turn off autoescape I wrote above. For details, click [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping)  . It explains everything. Will this help u?

Comment: This is the block: <div class="cuerpo"> {{ post.cuerpo|safe|linebreaks }} </div> This show the rich text body of my blog post. The problem I have is when I want to show some code, specially html tags. I use the highlightjs to edit the code block between <pre><code> Code to render </pre></code> but if it's html it only shows empty boxes... I need to shows the html tags as plain text but with django "safe" I think is not possible

Comment: I see, maybe it's because this: [If you are chaining filters, a filter applied after safe can make the contents unsafe again.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe). So you really should try `{{post.cuerpo|linebreaks|safe}}`. Or use autoescape.

Comment: Didn't work. Can't hightlight (or at least) show html as plain text using "safe" in my blogpost